# Vue 3 Date time Format in moment.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am struggling to convert the date-time formate in Vue.js 3. Somehow moment.js not working in Vue 3 version as I see. can anyone help me?

Thanks

vue file

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p class="text-danger">
      {{ dateTime(category.created_at) }}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import moment from "moment";
export default {
  computed: {
    dateTime(value) {
      return moment(value).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

`getting error`

http://prntscr.com/10z3p80

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Computed properties don't take arguments, but methods do. You probably either want this:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p class="text-danger">
      {{ dateTime(category.created_at) }}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import moment from 'moment';

export default {
  methods: {
    dateTime(value) {
      return moment(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Or something like this:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p class="text-danger">{{ formattedDate }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import moment from 'moment';

export default {
  computed: {
    formattedDate {
      return moment(this.category.created_at).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Edit: Corrected spelling

Comment: Thanks for this using mathods options it's work for me

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer the [`<script setup>`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#basic-syntax) way:

```js
<template>
    <div class="">
        <div class=""> {{ moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD") }} </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import moment from "moment";

let props = defineProps({
    date: String,
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filters as well.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p class="text-danger">
      {{ category.created_at | dateFormat }}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
```

and

```
filters: {
   dateFormat(date) {
       return moment(date, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("YYYY-MM-DD"); 
   }
}
```

Important to add format example **"YYYY-MM-DD"** to **moment(date, "YYYY-MM-DD")** without format in the first part it returns an Invalid Date in Safari and Firefox but works on Chrome.